# Django not receiving GET request from Javascript jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-urls

I am attempting to get some data via Ajax for a web app I am building. When I load the following function I am not seeing a GET request from Django but I do see the first alert pop up. I am new to JS and jQuery so please excuse my ignorance but I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```js
function get_file_system(){
    alert('in alert');
    $.getJSON("ajax/load_file_system/", function (data) {
        alert('in alert 2');
        var top_line = '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>"+ data.current_dir +"</p>';
        $('#file_system_jumbo').text(top_line).append('<ul class="list-group" id="file_system_list"></ul>');
        $.each(data.child_dirs, function(value){
            $('#file_system_list').append('<li class="list-group-item"><p><a href="?ajax/load_file_systemnew_dir={{ value.1 }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>{{ value.0 }}</a></p></li>')
        });
        $.each(data.child_files, function(value){
            $('#file_system_list').append('<li class="list-group-item"><p><a href="ajax/load_file_system?new_dir={{ value.1 }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>{{ value.0 }}</a></p></li>')
        });
    })
}

get_file_system();
```

Finally I have this in my urls.py file.

```
url(r'^ajax/load_file_system/$', views.load_file_system, name='load_file_system'),
```

Thanks for the hep.

Comment: Try if it will be working with slash in the beginning $.getJSON("/ajax/load_file_system/"

Comment: Try with  `$.getJSON("{% url 'load_file_system' %}", function (data) { ...`

Comment: Add that in but it still doesn't call the function. Putting "http://localhost:8000/ajax/load_file_system/" in the browser returns the JSON string so I know that part works. 

edit: I have tried both of the above with no success.

Comment: Can you provide the `views.py` and `urls.py` along with the expect JSON string? I would like to debug this locally.

Comment: I figured out what it was. I was running a local instance of jQuery and I simply had an error in the src of the script. Thanks for all the help though!